# Receiving a JSON response from the BOX Api when requesting a ticket

Tags: box-api

I am trying to request a "ticket" from the [Box API in order to authenticate a user](http://developers.box.com/get-started/#authenticating)
. Apparently it will only send back an XML response. I am sure it has something to do with the fact that BOX is still using the 1.0 API for this user authentication process. Is there a way to receive a JSON response for the 1.0 API or use the 2.0 API for this process?

- https://www.box.com/api/**1.0**/rest?action=get_ticket&api_key={api key}
  returns XML response.
- https://www.box.com/api/**2.0**/rest?action=get_ticket&api_key={api key}
  returns an error in JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This endpoint currently does not return JSON. We are moving our authentication system to OAuth2, which will return both JSON and XML as the rest of the V2 API does.

Comment: Any estimates on how long that will be?